# Can I execute an executable file from a webview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to execute an executable file(.bat/.sh) from a webview? I have a button on a webview and would like to run the executable when that button is clicked. I looked into window.open(...) and ActiveXObject() but since a webview is not a browser window, they are irrelevant.

Comment: Do you want to execute a local .bag or .sh and show the output in a webview? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way. A webview communicates with your node env using the vscode api using the postMessage function. In the node env, you can spawn and handle a child process. 
Docs:

1. [VSCode postMessage](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview#_passing-messages-from-an-extension-to-a-webview)
2. [Node childProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Edit 1: 
Example: [VSCode Extension Tutorial](https://github.com/hoovercj/vscode-extension-tutorial/blob/master/README.md)

Let me know if you need further help. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by contributing a Command which executes the script, and then creating a link that runs that command using a command URI in the WebView.

Let's call the command `my.ext.runScript`. Then we can add in our webview:

`<a href="command:my.ext.runScript">Run Script</a>`

Clicking that link will then invoke the script.

edit: [Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/ff13d20dc488cc41e80f61c9525da21c89368af0/src/vs/workbench/parts/welcome/page/electron-browser/vs_code_welcome_page.ts)

edit 2: You can also pass a message from the webview to your extension to invoke the command - [documentation here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview#_passing-messages-from-a-webview-to-an-extension).

Good luck!

Comment: But this doesn't run the script directly from the Webview. It will always detour to the extension to have it do the actual invocation. However, even though not directly asked for that might be a possible workaround.

Comment: I'm not really sure how one would execute a shell script "directly from" a webpage, I think this is as good as OP will get.

Comment: I tried doing what Tim suggested but was unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible. You don't have any browser or Node.js environment available in the web view. Also for security reasons the webview is pretty limited in what it can do, besides showing HTML content.